# MySQL performance issue in Soalris 10 with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, solaris-10

I have performance issue in MySQL 5.6 upgrade.

OS version : Solaris 10

Language : Perl script

MySQL version : MySQL upgraded from 5.1 (logical upgrade- Installed 5.6 on same sever and restored it in 5.6)

Memory : 64 GB

I have upgraded MYSQL form 5.1 to 5.6 in solaris 10 and converted all mysql tables from MYISAM to INNODB because mysql 5.6 have default storage engine as INNODB. My database size is 4.5 GB and added the parameters for the innodb.

```
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=512 M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5 G
```

My application is creating some temporary tables while doing the transactions so I have created `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` to 512 M .

In the application there are 3 modules and 2 are working fine and in third module it is very slow compared to MySQL 5.1. It contains nearly 20+ update statements and doing some joins with the temporary tables and master tables contains 2 million records in some tables.

I have the explain plan and done the profiling on the queries. In the profiling I observed sending data is taking huge time because of this performance is degraded.

Can anyone suggest on this to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar issues with solaris10 and mysql upgrade from 5.1 to 5.6.
I did the logical upgrade and while restoration it took lat time to restore 1Gb database. I have tried with inplace upgrde and found the similar issues with performance.

Just I have solaris 10 server which is running from the past 3.5 yeasrs. so i have  restarted my server so that all the cache was cleared and after the restart I have started my all databases services.

NOTE : Before doing the restart stop all the services and better to create another 5.1 database version and take the backup and start the inplace upgrade activity. It is better to go with inplace rather than doing the logical upgrade. Both are same but while restore it will take more time.